# How to import lwjgl_util

Tags: java, java-io, lwjgl

I am trying to make a 3d lwjgl object, and have done so, but am getting an error telling me that I don't have the XPMFile. So I did some research, and have found that I need to load the XPMFile, but can't seem to find out how to do so. So I am wondering how to load the XPMFile for lwjgl_Util.

**EDIT****

Ok, I've decided to change the question to fit what I know now. The new Question is:

How do you import lwjgl_util, so that you don't get the XPMFile error???

Answer (score 0):

have you put lwjgl_util.jar on the classpath? (i.e. the same place you put lwjgl.jar in eclipse).

Comment: I have put org.lwjgl.util.glu.GLU, i don't think that this is the lwjgl_util, but i don't know what the import is for lwjgl_util.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general package.

import org.lwjgl.util.*;